# How do I get the bars in this ggplot2 geom_bar graph to use Rcolorbrewer palette?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have been trying to get my graph bars to display as Rcolorbrewer "Set1" palette but everything I try creates a graph with gray bars. This is the code I've tried:

```
total_enrollment_by_year_plot <- ggplot(data = total_enrollment_by_year) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Total_Enrollments), stat = "identity") +
labs(
title = "Total Patient Enrollment by Year, 2018-2020",
x = "Year", # x-axis label
y = "Patients Enrolled") + # y-axis label
scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

I also got desperate and tried to create my own legend to add colors to each bar and it didn't work either:

```
total_enrollment_by_year_plot <- ggplot(data = total_enrollment_by_year) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Total_Enrollments), stat = "identity") +
labs(
title = "Total Patient Enrollment by Year, 2018-2020",
x = "Year", # x-axis label
y = "Patients Enrolled") + # y-axis label
scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = c("2018" = "Green", "2019" = "Blue", "2020"
                                       = "Orange", "All Years" = "Red"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a fill into your aes and you should use scale_fill_brewer not scale_color_brewer.

```
total_enrollment_by_year_plot <- ggplot(data = total_enrollment_by_year) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Total_Enrollments, fill = Year), stat = "identity") +
labs(
title = "Total Patient Enrollment by Year, 2018-2020",
x = "Year", # x-axis label
y = "Patients Enrolled") + # y-axis label
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```